# GIT: Gitflow workflow

Tags: git, github, git-flow

I've created the branchA from branch develop

```
# git checkout -b branchA
# git push origin -u branchA
```

modify some files

```
# git add *
# git commit -m "modification in branchA"
# git push
# git checkout develop
# git merge branchA
# git push
```

then I've created another branch

```
# git checkout -b branchB
# git push origin -u branchB
```

modify some files

```
# git add *
# git commit -m "modification in branchB"
# git push
# git checkout develop
# git merge branchB
# git push
```

Then again working in branchA

```
# git checkout branchA
```

I modified 1 JSP (home.jsp)

```
# git add *
# git commit -m "modification in branchA"
# git push
# git checkout develop
# git merge branchA
# git push
```

Then I come back to branchB

```
# git checkout branchB
# git pull
```

But I don't have the changes I made in home.jsp

Comment: A branch doesn’t stay associated with its “parent branch” (in quotes, because that’s not a real thing – a branch is just a pointer to a commit). Look at `git log --graph --all` and run `git merge develop`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, use `git push` only on tracking branches, if you haven't set your branch as tracking one, it's always safer to use `git push origin branch_name`. You can create a new tracking branch easily though by

```
git branch --track branch-name origin/branch-name
git branch --set-upstream-to <remote-branch> # for existing branches
```

Now, if I'm getting it right, you made the change in branchA in second last step and merged it into develop, but you haven't updated the branchB with changes in develop yet. That's why you see no changes in branchB from branchA. Just because you forked out branchB from develop, doesn't mean it would always stay updated with changes in develop.

```
git checkout branchB
git merge develop
```

Now the changes you made should be reflected in branchB

Comment: git pull just fetches all the remote changes, but update only the current branch and that too with the changes from remote, not with changes in develop.